# Extract text from many structured web pages

Tags: html, phantomjs

The web site donedeal.ie does not provide the capability to search or filter by certain fields which I want to filter by. I am trying to get the link to each result page from the search results pages. Then I would like to extract some text from these result web pages which have the same structure.

I have downloaded some search result list pages and have examined the HTML. I looked into using sed to extract the links to each individual result. Then I thought I should use the DOM somehow. I have been using PhantomJS and the Javascript console in Chrome developer tools.

This is an example of a results list page.
http://cars.donedeal.ie/find/cars/for-sale/Ireland/?filters%5BbodyType%5D=Saloon&ranges%5Bprice_from%5D=1000&ranges%5Bprice_to%5D=10000&sort=price&source=ALL

This is an example of an individual result page.
http://cars.donedeal.ie/cars-for-sale/01-passat/8313920

Each link is in a `div` with `class="listing-info"`. The first element of that `div` is another `div` and the first element of this `div` is an `a` element.

```
<div class="listing-info">
    <div class="title"><a href="http://cars.donedeal.ie/cars-for-sale/renault-megane/7911289" title="renault megane" > ... </a></div>

    ...

</div>
```

It is this `href` link that I am trying to get for all results on all pages at the moment.

The following is markup from an individual result page.

```
<div class="mainAdArea">
    ...
    <table class="extraAdDetails">
        <tbody>
            ...
            <tr>
                <td class="value">Manual</td>
                <td class="value">Petrol</td>
                <td class="value">1.6 litre</td>
            </tr>
            ...
            <tr>
                ...
                <td class="value">
                    Mar 2015 </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I would like the extracted information to look something like this:

Manual,Petrol,1.6 litre, ... ,Mar 2015

I think the easiest way to use the information would be to extract the information for each page onto 1 line in CSV format. I am completely open to suggestions however.

What is the easiest way to do any of this?

Comment: Now that it is clearer what you need, how about you clarify, what kind of answers you expect. Do you expect complete solutions or general guidance with PhantomJS? Furthermore, if it is about scraping sites that work even without JS, why don't you use scrapy or mechanize with their DOM implementation?

Comment: I did look at Scrapy but I thought it would be simpler to use Javascript with PhantomJS. I have used Javascript before but not PhantomJS or Python. Maybe it's actually easier to use Scrapy though. I don't expect complete solutions. Any guidance at all is helpful. It doesn't have to be PhantomJS. Guidance with Scrapy or anything would be good too. I added the markup on the pages containing the data. Hopefully this is what you were asking for.